# CastError mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using mongodb in an express/nodejs project. I have a nested schema such that Themes have categories

Given this schema:

```
var ControlCategorySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        Required: 'Please enter the category name'
    }
});
ControlCategorySchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'ControlCategorySchemaCounter');

var ThemeSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    category : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ControlCategorySchema'}
});
ThemeSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'ThemeCounter');
```

And the following controller code:

```
exports.create_a_theme = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.category);
    if (req.body.category != undefined) {
        addTheme(req,res,req.body.category);
    }

};

function addTheme(req,res,category_id) {
    console.log("category id " + category_id);
    ControlCategory.findById(category_id, function (err, category_found) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err)

        req.body.category = category_found;
        console.log("body is " + req.body.category);
        var new_theme = new Theme();
        new_theme.name = req.body.name;
        new_theme.category = req.body.category;
        new_theme.save(function (err, theme) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            console.log(theme);
            res.json(theme);
        });
    });
}
```

Can anyone help solve why posting this json

```
{ 
    "name": "Application Security",
    "category": 0
}
```

Results in the error below:

```
{
  "errors": {
    "category": {
      "message": "Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"{ _id: 0, name: 'Application Security', __v: 0 }\" at path \"category\"",
      "name": "CastError",
      "stringValue": "\"{ _id: 0, name: 'Application Security', __v: 0 }\"",
      "kind": "ObjectID",
      "value": {
        "_id": 0,
        "name": "Application Security",
        "__v": 0
      },
      "path": "category",
      "reason": {
        "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ _id: 0, name: 'Application Security', __v: 0 }\" at path \"category\"",
        "name": "CastError",
        "stringValue": "\"{ _id: 0, name: 'Application Security', __v: 0 }\"",
        "kind": "ObjectId",
        "value": {
          "_id": 0,
          "name": "Application Security",
          "__v": 0
        },
        "path": "category"
      }
    }
  },
  "message": "Theme validation failed",
  "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

One thing that is very strange is that I do virtually the same thing on another schema and controller code and it works!

```
var AssessmentSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        Required: 'Kindly enter the name of the assessment'
    },
    Created_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    status: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'AssessmentStatus' },
});

var AssessmentStatusSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        Required: 'Please enter the name of the assessment status'
    }

});

exports.create_an_assessment = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.status);
    if (req.body.status == undefined) {
        AssessmentStatus.findOne({"name": "Due For Assessment"}, function (err, assessment_status) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            addAssessment(req,res,assessment_status._id);
        });
    }
    else {

        addAssessment(req,res,req.body.status);
    }

};

function addAssessment(req,res,status_id) {
    console.log("status id " + status_id);
    AssessmentStatus.findById(status_id, function (err, assessment_status) {
        if (err)
            res.send(err)
        req.body.status = assessment_status;
        console.log("body is " + req.body.status);
        var new_assessment = new Assessment();
        new_assessment.name = req.body.name;
        new_assessment.status = assessment_status;
        new_assessment.save(function (err, assessment) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            console.log(assessment);
            res.json(assessment);
        });
    });
}
```

And there I post same kind of data

```
{
    "name": "Assessment 10",
    "status": 6
}
```

and get the desired result

```
{
  "__v": 0,
  "_id": 28,
  "status": {
    "_id": 6,
    "name": "Due For Assessment",
    "__v": 0
  },
  "name": "Assessment 10",
  "Created_date": "2017-03-31T06:48:21.999Z"
}
```

I cant tell what is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Error occurs when you provide an invalid ObjectId

The mongo `_id` is 12-byte BSON type ObjectId

here I have added `if-else` to verify whether the `category_id` is a Valid ObjectId or not, if it's then do the Operation, else throw an custom error message

When you are Using `mongoose-autoincrement-package`
it uses `Number` type instead of `ObjectId` and
the ref property type will be a `Number` instead of `ObjectId`, so when you declare the references  remember to change the reference property's type to `Number` instead of `ObjectId` if the referenced model is also using the plugin.

---

```
var ThemeSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    category : {type: Number, ref: 'ControlCategorySchema'}
});
```

---

```
function addTheme(req, res, category_id) {
    console.log("category id " + category_id);
    var cond = mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(category_id)

    if (cond) {
        ControlCategory.findById(category_id, function (err, category_found) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)

            req.body.category = category_found;
            console.log("body is " + req.body.category);
            var new_theme = new Theme();
            new_theme.name = req.body.name;
            new_theme.category = req.body.category._id;
            new_theme.save(function (err, theme) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);
                console.log(theme);
                res.json(theme);
            });
        });
    } else {
        res.json({ message: 'not a valid object id' });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but gives same problem i.e. goes into the if (cond) block and get same error

Comment: what is the value of `category_id`

Comment: I am using var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment'); so my _id is an autoincrementing counter. As such the cond is passing as true

Comment: MongoDB Enterprise > db.controlcategories.find();
{ "_id" : 0, "name" : "Application Security", "__v" : 0 }

Comment: Instead of  `ControlCategory.findById(category_id, function` try 
 `ControlCategory.findById({_id: category_id}`,

If that doesn't work then do 
 `ControlCategory.findOne({_id: category_id}`

Comment: Same problem. I suspect its got to do with the new_theme part as the findbyId and findOne both return the correct category as in console i'm seeing "body is { _id: 0, name: 'Application Security', __v: 0 }" from console.log("body is " + req.body.category);

Comment: do `new_theme.category = req.body.category._id;`

Comment: {
  "errors": {
    "categoryobj": {
      "message": "Cast to ObjectID failed for value \"0\" at path \"categoryobj\"",
      "name": "CastError",
      "stringValue": "\"0\"",
      "kind": "ObjectID",
      "value": 0,
      "path": "categoryobj",
      "reason": {
        "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"0\" at path \"categoryobj\"",
        "name": "CastError",
        "stringValue": "\"0\"",
        "kind": "ObjectId",
        "value": 0,
        "path": "categoryobj"
      }
 }
  },
  "message": "Theme validation failed",
  "name": "ValidationError"
}

Comment: try converting the `_id` to ObjectId `var id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.category._id)`; and then `new_theme.category = id;`

Comment: It stores it but is not right as I get
db.themes.find()
{ "_id" : 8, "category" : ObjectId("00000000dd3a51953427d19e"), "name" : "Application Security", "__v" : 0 }
which has no link to
MongoDB Enterprise > db.controlcategories.find();
{ "_id" : 0, "name" : "Application Security", "__v" : 0 }
and so .populate() in must listing fails later

Comment: You have to make Change in Schema, Instead of `category : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ControlCategorySchema'}` do `category : {type: Number, ref: 'ControlCategorySchema'}` in the ThemeSchema, this is how the references are declared to Number type instead of ObjectId

Answer (score 0):

`ThemeSchema.category` is of type `Schema.Types.ObjectId` and `'0'` is not a valid mongo id. A valid mongo id would be 12-byte hexadecimal, for example `507f1f77bcf86cd799439011`.

You have two options here, either define `ThemeSchema.category` as a `number` or assign valid mongo id. Since you are referring `ControlCategorySchema` in `ThemeSchema`, I guess later is the only option here.

Comment: given that my _id is an autoincrement using the mongoose-auto-increment plugin would this not make the 0 valid?

Comment: here is the db entry MongoDB Enterprise > db.controlcategories.find();
{ "_id" : 0, "name" : "Application Security", "__v" : 0 }

Answer (score 0):

Looks like https://stackoverflow.com/users/5127888/p0k8 gave a working answer, thank you!

Instead of category : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ControlCategorySchema'} do category : {type: Number, ref: 'ControlCategorySchema'}

That worked. Although still puzzles me why the Assessment one worked out

Comment: I guess the referenced model is not using the plugin something like `AssessmentStatusSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'AssessmentStatus');`

Comment: No it also uses it AssessmentSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'AssessmentCounter');

Comment: if mine answer was correct about solving the problem you faced, then please accept the answer and mark it as solution, which will help other too to solve the problem, if they are looking for